# Page viewer not swiping between views

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

SO after looking at the samples from viewpagerindicator I realised that they are all in fragment form.

I wanted to do this without fragments which I tried to do but after it compiles it displays the first layout but does not swipe to the other views.

I was looking at the "SampleIconsDefault.java" (from the samples) and made my own and thought I had it right but I have no idea why it doesn't swipe.

The activity & adaptor:

```
package russellrargill.work.burghcoffeehouseapp;

import com.viewpagerindicator.IconPageIndicator;
import com.viewpagerindicator.IconPagerAdapter;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    //variables for the pager
    ViewPager thePager;
    IconPageIndicator theIconPageIndicator;
    MyPagerAdapter theAdapter;

    private Context cxt;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home_layout);

    //set the context
    cxt = this;

    theAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter();

    thePager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.the_pager);
    thePager.setAdapter(theAdapter);

    theIconPageIndicator = (IconPageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.icon_page_indicator);
    theIconPageIndicator.setViewPager(thePager);


}//END onCreate()

class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter implements IconPagerAdapter {

    String[] titles = new String[]{"Home","Menu","Stores","About Us","Contact"};
    protected final int[] ICONS = new int[] {
            R.drawable.perm_group_calendar,
            R.drawable.perm_group_camera,
            R.drawable.perm_group_device_alarms,
            R.drawable.perm_group_location
    };

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, int position) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)cxt.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_layout, null);    
            collection.addView(layout,0);
            //TODO add layouts for each page

            layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pagelayoot, null);    
            collection.addView(layout,1);

            layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page2layoot, null);    
            collection.addView(layout,2);
            return layout;
    }

    private int mCount = titles.length;

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mCount;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
      return titles[position % titles.length];
    }

    @Override
    public int getIconResId(int index) {
      return ICONS[index % ICONS.length];
    }

    public void setCount(int count) {
        if (count > 0 && count <= 10) {
            mCount = count;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
        return (arg0==arg1);
    }
    }
}//END CLASS
```

The main xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center|top"
android:background="#000000"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
android:padding="1dp"
tools:context=".HomeScreen" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/nav_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >


    <com.viewpagerindicator.IconPageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/icon_page_indicator"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/the_pager"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />

</LinearLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/nav_layout" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="banana\nbabababba\newfewfewfg\nwefewf"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="banana\nbabababba\newfewfewfg\nwefewf"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="banana\nbabababba\newfewfewfg\nwefewf"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="banana\nbabababba\newfewfewfg\nwefewf"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="banana\nbabababba\newfewfewfg\nwefewf"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="banana\nbabababba\newfewfewfg\nwefewf"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="banana\nbabababba\newfewfewfg\nwefewf"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="banana\nbabababba\newfewfewfg\nwefewf"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="banana\nbabababba\newfewfewfg\nwefewf"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="banana\nbabababba\newfewfewfg\nwefewf"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="banana\nbabababba\newfewfewfg\nwefewf"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="banana\nbabababba\newfewfewfg\nwefewf"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            />



    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

the other 2 layouts (almost identical so I'll only post one)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="TEST"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView4"
    android:text="A"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView3"
    android:text="IS"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="98dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView2"
    android:text="THIS"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

Ignore some of the messiness of it all, it was slightly rushed.

Any assistance as to why it doesn't scroll would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: wait a minute...do you want your activities to be swiped??i don't think that is even possible

Comment: Not activites! You can use the library from http://viewpagerindicator.com/ with the android v4 support library to create a viewpager (V4 support library) and a title indicator (viewpagerindicator). I managed to convert the first example from the website but I got stuck with their icon example

Comment: yeah but what will you swipe ?? pages have to be of some form...either activities or fragments...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one of the fragments......these have to be independant for each fragment you create.......and make a note that my adapter may be different from yours i made a change in the adapter so that i don't have to use the "context" thing again and again...

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class FragmentPlaylists extends Fragment {
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_b, container, false);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i am building an app right now which does the same thing....but it has many things extra you would have to sort it out...would you like the code for that?

Comment: yes it works....but you would have to remove the extra elemnts...and do the renaming of the  variable and pages and all

Comment: Then yes please! I'll break it down until I can compare it and find out what I did wrong! thank you! p.s.(sorry if I offended you earlier I thought it might not compile as it is a work in progress :P)

Comment: no problem, and you didn't offend me....i have posted one more answer...i would be posting one more answer as well but i will have to wait 3 minutes as this site won't allow me to post so often

Comment: do tell me if i was of any help

i would recommend that you use my code..as it appears more neat....

Comment: Ah I totally didn't make my question clear enough, I wanted to do it without fragments. But now that you have posted them If I decide to go down this route I shall use them for reference!

Comment: yeah i read that a bit later.... and why do you want to do it without fragments??i think that is not even possible (just what i think)

Comment: I guess because I've only developed simple apps that are based on api 8/android 2.2 without any of the fancy features but I guess I should start sometime. plus I got the first example from the website working so I thought why not try another! haha

Comment: which website? and what did you use instead of the fragment??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35232/discussion-between-ankit-srivastava-and-russell-cargill)

Comment: Hey do you know how to put php in android?

Comment: hey would you do me a favor?

Comment: hmm what can I do for you?

Comment: Well i don't need help right now...well the thing is my emulator won't connect to the internet...so usually i borrow   a friends phone..but last night he was asleep..so i needed someone to run a small  code for me....and do you know how to pass info directly between fragments?in the docs it says" All Fragment-to-Fragment communication is done through the associated Activity. Two Fragments should never communicate directly." but i wanna do it directly

Answer (score 1):

code for the adapter

package sourcecode.jazzplayer;

```
import java.util.List; 

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;

public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private List<Fragment> fragments;
    private static String[] titles = new String[] {"Songs", "My Playlists", "Artists","Albums"};

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
        super(fm);
        this.fragments = fragments;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return this.fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.fragments.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getPageTitle( int position )
    {
        return titles[ position ];
    }
}
```

code for the activity that creates the fragments

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

public class MyMusic  extends FragmentActivity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mymusic);


           List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
            fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, FragmentSongs.class.getName()));
            fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, FragmentArtists.class.getName()));
            fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, FragmentPlaylists.class.getName()));
            fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, FragmentAlbums.class.getName())); 


            ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(super.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);


            ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)super.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);



            pager.setAdapter(adapter);
            pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);

            pager.setCurrentItem(0);




    }


}
```